# Why is the date in the nav bar of the mini calendar not being displayed properly in some browsers?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Can anyone tell me why the date (i.e. "January 2012") in the nav bar of the mini calendar at the top of the right column is being displayed as two lines of text instead of one on some computers using IE7&8???  Seems to render properly in other browsers...  I have researched but cannot find a solution.

http://www.stamfordsymphony.org/indexGLK.php

Thank you!

Comment: It looks proper to me on IE8.

Comment: @JustinSatyr: Try compatibility mode.

Answer (score 3):

The `width: 70px;` on your `.monthYearRow` CSS class is not wide enough for the text in compatibility mode. In non-compatibility view, your specified width is ignored in favor of maximizing the size of the table cell.

Simply remove the `width` line altogether from that class, or at least override it using the element's id if necessary.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to click the checkbox next to this answer to mark it as *the* answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is causing the problem, but removing unnecessary style rules will certainly narrow it down.  for instance, when I remove the width attribute on .monthYearRow in your style sheet, the issue disappears (at least for IE 9 running as IE 7).

Try just whittling away style rules until you find which one is the offender.